# Can't use existing Storage account when opening Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

While opening `Cloud Shell`, then choosing `Powershell` and `More advanced settings` for subscription I can't see already existing Storage Account. Is it a bug or done on purpose? When I choose `Create new` and use already existsing storage account then it works as expected but why can't I choose this account with `Use existing` button?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have one existing storage account with an **File Share** like below:

[image]

Now, I selected **`PowerShell`** in **Azure Cloud Shell** as below:
[image]
I clicked **Show advanced settings** by selecting my subscription like below:
[image]
When I tried to select **`Use existing`** button, I too can't see already existing Storage Account like below:

[image]

Please **note** that, *Cloud Shell region* and *Storage account location* should be **`same`** while using existing resources.

When I selected the same *Cloud Shell region*, I can see the ***existing Storage Account*** like below:

[image]

After clicking **`Attach Storage`**, selected storage account and file share linked to Azure Cloud Shell successfully.

To confirm that, you can run below **PowerShell** command and get the details of current file share:

```
Get-CloudDrive
```

**Response:**

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/ikA1GgR.png)]